# meaning of "über"

Tags: meaning, preposition

Can anyone explain to me why the word *über* is used in this sentence:

> Frauen reagieren eher als Männer auf neue Erkenntnisse **über** nützliche und schädliche Lebensmittel und orientieren sich gesünder.

Answer (score 2):

"*Über*" is needed to inform the reader about which topic they gained new knowledge (in this case use and harmful food):

> to gain knowledge **about** sth.
>
> *Erkenntnisse **über** etw. erlangen*

"*Über*" has different meanings for many cases as you can see [here](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ueber_auf_darueber_darauf) (german source) or [here](http://www.dict.cc/?s=%C3%BCber) (english source). The meaning depends on the context the word appears in.

Comment: *Über* is the *Übervater* of prepositions.